# Logical question: REST-API caching of list responses

Tags: java, elasticsearch, caching, rest

I have a logical question (is logical the right word?) to general caching of database responses in a rest API environment. I use elasticsearch for this. The caching (saving and retrieve entries) is no problem. Also, requesting specific entities by id is ok. My problem is in the area of list responses. Here is the problem:

Database layout for better understanding:

```
| ID | firstname | lastname |
-----------------------------
| 1  | John1     | Dow1     |
| 2  | John2     | Dow2     |
| 3  | John3     | Dow3     |
| 4  | John4     | Dow4     |
```

You have 4 entries in a database and request 2 (the last two, offset 2 with limit 2. Here it would be ID 3 and 4) of them (pagination). These two entities get saved to elastic for a fast second query. The next time you request the list and select the first page (offset 0, limit 2. Here ID 1 and 2). Now elastic checks if there is something in the cache and finds the first two selected entries (ID 3 and 4) and returns them. But these are the wrong entries, because we requested the first page which should be ID 1 and 2.

My solution for now is to do a count query (hit database) to check how many entries should be there (in this example it would be 4 total entries) and if elastic has less, I query the database and update the cache. The right order is ensured by the **order by clause** and works if all entries are there. But this involves always a hit on the database and destroys (a little) the advantages of the cache.

Is this a general problem with caching lists results or is there any solution i could use for this? Maybe my solution is good (but i don't think so :) ). I have to say that this service is not used by millions of users ... it aims a user base of a few thousand. Maybe always hitting the database in this case is ok?

Thanks for your help in advance! Sorry for possible spelling errors ... I even used a spell checker :)

Comment: For the second time, your query changes offset, so it won't get the records from cache. What cache settings you are using ?

Comment: I use the default settings for elastic. But the second query in elastic starts at position 0 and has a size of 2. And at this position are the IDs 3 and 4 and not 1 and 2, because i selected 3 and 4 first and then 1 and 2.

Comment: I'm interested to know why you don't use 'standard' caching frameworks. Especially with Spring Boot, it's possible to integrate these frameworks easily: https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/

Comment: I´m using standard caching frameworks. This is an official library for the ebean ORM Framework. I just wanted to know, if it is possible/good to cache list responses or only single enittys.